# How can I move only my website, not email, to a DigitalOcean droplet?

Tags: linux, networking

I have a website and email on a VPS with cPanel. I'm ready to launch the new website on a different droplet with Digital Ocean. How can I achieve this and keep all email and email forwarders on my old server?

[Here's a screenshot of my current zone file in cPanel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jSEC.png)

Comment: This is fairly straightforward to do, but the fact that you're using cPanel throws a wrench into things. Ditch cPanel first. This will enable you to truly learn the skills needed to understand how your server works, and what will need to change to accomplish your goals.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the domain's DNS *A-RR* (resource record) to point at a new server's IP, while setting up an *MX* DNS RR pointing at old IP.

Comment: Do you have an example of doing this with cpanel?

Comment: Nope. I don't use any panels.